# Access html select box using javascript with static prefix

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have multiple different html inputs with same string prefix. I'd like to re-use input for validation and create reusable validation statement. Something like that:

```
 var input_name="oil_level";

 if(document.myform.input_name+"_pretrip".value=="" || document.myform.input_name+"_posttrip".value=="")
 {
     alert("Please enter oil level value!");
     form_ok = false;
 }
```

I am trying to concatenate input_name+"_pretrip" where is "_pretrip" is static string prefix, so that way I can use different values for input_name variable and reuse this code.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bracket notation (square brackets) to access object property in this case:

```
document.myform[input_name + "_pretrip"].value == ""
```

Good to read at MDN: [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)